Is there a scripting call that is identical to the menu 'File/Open' (Ctrl+O)
With the menu File/Open I can pick a directory and a file within.  Is there a scripting call that returns the path and file name?  boolean OpenFile(string directory, string filename)

Are you saying you want the script to open a file, or are you saying you want a way to capture the last file that the user opened by hand?

I want to make a script where the user opens a file just as with the menu item.  I had hoped for a scripting call that would give me the file name and path once the user has made the pick.  I need that info for the next steps.
...
Not so nice:  the user has to open the file first and then I follow up with GetFrontImage() or similar and take it from there.

I think you are looking for the OpenDialog() command with it's extended signature:
RealNumber opendialog( String selected_path )
Boolean OpenDialog( Window par_win, String prompt, String default_path, String pathname )

As example:
string prompt = "Please select file."
string default = GetApplicationDirectory("open_save",0)
string returned 
if ( OpenDialog(NULL,prompt,default,returned) )
    OKDialog("User selected:\n"+returned)

